# Merge matrices alternating columns: x number of cols from the first and y number from the second

Tags: r, matrix, merge

Hopefully this is simple, but it seems tricky to explain!

I want to combine two matrices in R, but I'd like to take the first two columns from the first matrix as the first two rows of the combined matrix, then the first column in the second matrix as the third column in the new matrix, then the 4th and 5th columns of the new matrix would be the 3rd and 4th from the first matrix and so and so forth. All matrices have the same row names and same number of rows

Matrix 1:

```
  1 2 1 2 1 2
A a b c d e f
B a b c d e f
C a b c d e f
```

Matrix 2:

```
  3 3 3
A x x x
B y y y
C z z z
```

Desired Matrix:

```
  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
A a b x c d x e f x
B a b y c d y e f y
C a b z c d z e f z
```

In my example I need this (1,2)(3)(1,2)(3) configuration but as the post title suggests it would be cool to have a generic way of doing this for any configuration of columns from the matrices to be merged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a set of column indexes and then subset a `cbind`-ed version of the pair of matrices:

```
grp1 <- 2
grp2 <- 1
sel <- c(rbind(
  matrix(1:ncol(mat1),ncol=ncol(mat1)/grp1),
  matrix(1:ncol(mat2),ncol=ncol(mat2)/grp2) + ncol(mat1)
))
# 'sel' looks like this before coercion to a vector.
# You can see how the alternating numbers fit together here:
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    5
#[2,]    2    4    6
#[3,]    7    8    9
cbind(mat1,mat2)[,sel]

  1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3  
A "a" "b" "x" "c" "d" "x" "e" "f" "x"
B "a" "b" "y" "c" "d" "y" "e" "f" "y"
C "a" "b" "z" "c" "d" "z" "e" "f" "z"
```

Using the following objects as `mat1` and `mat2`:

```
mat1 <- as.matrix(read.table(text="1 2 1 2 1 2
A a b c d e f
B a b c d e f
C a b c d e f", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

mat2 <- as.matrix(read.table(text="3 3 3
A x x x
B y y y
C z z z", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

Comment: Nice use of the column-major features of R matrices using `rbind`.